# Adding a library to my makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have set up a makefile that takes the sources main.c, word.c, and trim.c
I also used a library which is called linkedList.a, however even after adding it it does not build as I keep getting undefined references to functions within linkedlist.

The following is my makefile code:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
SRCDIR = .
CC = gcc
YACC = bison -y
CDEBUG = -g
COMPLIANCE_FLAGS =
CFLAGS = $(COMPLIANCE_FLAGS) $(CDEBUG) -I. -I$(SRCDIR)
LDFLAGS = -g

LIBRARY_FILES = linkedList.a

linkedList.a: $(LIBRARY_FILES).o
    $(RM) -f $(output)
    $(AR) cr $(output) $(inputs)
    ranlib $(output)

############################################################################################################
# List your sources here.
SOURCES = main.c word.c trim.c
############################################################################################################

############################################################################################################
# list the name of your output program here.
EXECUTABLE = wordCounter
############################################################################################################
# Create the names of the object files (each .c file becomes a .o file)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

include $(SOURCES:.c=.d)

all : $(OBJS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE)  $(OBJS)

%.o : %.c #Defines how to translate a single c file into an object file.
    echo compiling $<
    echo $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E $< > $<.preout
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
    echo done compiling $<

%.d : %.c #Defines how to generate the dependencies for the given files.  -M gcc option generates dependencies.
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CC) $(COMPLIANCE_FLAGS ) -M $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
     rm -f $@.$$$$

clean :   # Delete any and all artifacts from the build.  The only thing which is kept is the source code.
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.preout
    rm -f *.s
    rm -f *.S
    rm -f *d
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I feel I added the proper items in the proper places. My best guess is that my library_files is somehow wrong?

Comment: Your `$(EXECUTABLE)` rule doesn't mention the library, it just tries to link `main.c`, `word.o`, and `trim.o`. Do you want some help rewriting that rule?

Comment: @Beta That would be very helpful, so yes please.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(EXECUTABLE)` rule doesn't mention the library, it just tries to link `main.o`, `word.o` and `trim.o`. So we must rewrite that rule.

First try this from the command line (because we can't do something with Make until we know how to do it without Make):

```
gcc -o wordCounter main.o word.o trim.o -L. -llinkedList
```

If this works, then we can write the rule:

```
$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJS) linkedList.a
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) -L. -llinkedList
```

If it doesn't, we'll have to tweak it a little. And some further refinements are possible, once we have the makefile working.

Answer (score 0):

The "all:" line needs enhancement and, yes, LIBRARY_FILES needs changing/splitting.  You have an OBJS variable for the executable, but nothing similar for the library.  Actually, a bit more to do, as follows ...

(1) Currently, you have one library, but let's go for two:

```
LIBRARY_FILES += lib1.a
LIBRARY_FILES += lib2.a
```

(2) We now need two variables, similar to your OBJS, but one for each library:

```
LIBOBJS1 += abc.o def.o
LIBOBJS2 += ghi.o jkl.o
```

(3) We now need two rules, one for each library, similar to your rule for your library, but different [Note that most modern "ar" programs do their own ranlib--YMMV]:

```
lib1.a: $(LIBOBJS1)
    ar crv $@ $(LIBOBJS1)

lib2.a: $(LIBOBJS2)
    ar crv $@ $(LIBOBJS2)
```

(4) Now, change the rule for the executable itself:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS) $(LIBRARY_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJS) $(LIBRARY_FILES)
```

(5) Now, we need to change the "all:" line. With the other rule changes, this can be simplified to:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

(6) Now add a command to the "clean:" target, either:

```
    rm -f *.a
```

Or:

```
    rm -f $(LIBRARY_FILES)
```

(7) Note that care must be taken so that LIBOBJS1/LIBOBJS2 don't overlap with SOURCES/OBJS.  That is, you have to decide which sources build the libraries and which ones are strictly for the executable.  I think you'll be fine on this, but I didn't see anything that spelled which .c/.o files you wanted to build your library from.

(8) All the build rules should probably be moved down the file *after* all the symbol definitions